# The vertical displacement of a curve

Tags: calculus

I am working on a specific problem in Turbulence and I have been dealing with the sensible heat cospectra in its pre-multiplied form. This above information is not relevant to the problem asked here but just serves as an introduction.

My question is,

Suppose I have a curve $y=f(x)$ which shows a maximum at some particular point and is also continuous throughout. Lets also say the curve is bounded between $0$ to $\infty$. The general form of the curve is unknown but its known how its two extreme ends behave. I have a particular situation here which is illustrated in the attached figure.
[Sample_Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svAFP.png)

The figure is hand drawn only but is approximately the experimental curve which I obtained (The differences $c_1$ and $c$ are bit exaggerated for better visualization). The two ends of the curve are known, where one is linear and other end is a power law of $-\frac{4}{3}$. Now the solid line shows the curve from one experimental level ($z_1$) and the dotted line from another experimental level ($z_2$). Now the two known ends of the curves are vertically displaced between the two levels by amount $c_1$ and $c$ respectively as shown in the figure. Here $c>c_1$, so the right end gets displaced more compared to the left. The middle portion where the curve is unknown gets vertically displaced upwards.

Now given the fact that $c_1$ and $c$ are not very large, Can I claim that the vertical upward displacement of the middle portion of the curve is proportional to the relative difference between $c_1$ and $c$? If yes, then what mathematical theorem allows me to do so?

I do not need a very exact answer, but just it has to be physical. I would very much appreciate the help from the experts here, so I may know whether I am right or wrong in this claim.